# Example of a weak Hausdorff space that is not Hausdorff?

Tags: gn.general-topology

I've looked on the web and haven't found a simple example.

Comment: From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Hausdorff_space  A space $X$ is weak Hausdorff if whenever $Y$ is compact Hausdorff and $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous, then $f(Y)$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow, Prof. Solovay.  Gerhard "And Happy Valentines Day, Too" Paseman, 2012.02.14 

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ has the property that every compact subset is closed. So it is certainly a weak Hausdorff space. But it isn't Hausdorff, as $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't locally compact.

**Addendum**

Another example is the [cocountable topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) on an uncountable set. No two points have disjoint neighbourhoods, and the only compact subsets are the finite subsets.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the one point compactification of Q". Of course, I am familiar with the one point compactification of a locally compact space.

What is the topology of this space. What are two points that don't have disjoint neighborhoods?

Comment: @BobSolovay: I was not sure of this myself, but consulting Kelley's book tells me that for any top. space X the 1-point compactification X* has as its open sets all the open subsets of X, together with all subsets of X* whose complements are closed compact subsets of X. (TBC)

Comment: Thus, if I have understood things correctly: when we give Q its subspace topology from R (thus not locally compact) we find that the open neighbourhoods of the point at infinity correspond to cofinite subsets of Q, and hence they meet every non-empty open subset of Q. (Open subsets of Q in this topology are either empty or infinite.)

Comment: @Bob Solovay: Yemon Choi's definition of the one-point compactification is correct. @Yemon Choi: But your second comment is wrong, since $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite compact subsets (e.g., any convergent sequence together with its limit forms a compact set). But every compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior, so it's true that every neighbourhood of the point at infinity meets every non-empty open set.

Answer (score 4):

Steen & Seebach's counterexample #99: [Maximal Compact Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&lpg=PA118&ots=3hHBTJE-k7&dq=maximal%20compact%20topology&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false) is another example. This is also a KC space (every compact set is closed) but not Hausdorff.